# How to implement sending messages to some user not to all sockets

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socketserver

How to send message instead to all clients in room, to specific user in default room based on username or id. Where I need to implement that, only on server site or? I know I am doing wrong and I am confused.

```
var numUsers = 0;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  var addedUser = false;

  // when the client emits 'new message', this listens and executes
  socket.on('new message', (data) => {
    // we tell the client to execute 'new message'
    socket.broadcast.emit('new message', {
      username: socket.username,
      message: data
    });
  });
```

I see in docs that code https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/ and how can I handle the ID for users, they changed in every re-connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

1.You can use your own data structure to store users information like socketId and other things or go for redis it is a good in memory data structure.

2.You have to store socketId for each user when a new connection is made on server using any of the above or some other method.

3.when you want to send the message to a particular user you need have it's socketId and use this code to send message:

```
 io.to(`${socketId}`).emit('hey', 'How are you');
```

4.When a user disconnects just delete the user's info like socketId and other info which you have.

So, when a user join your server save his info and when he leaves just delete it.

Now suppose you have four users connected on your server. just create a array of object to keep the track of users and socket ids. when new user connects just push into the array and when a user exit just loop through the array and when socketId matches just remove that object from array simple

```
 let users = [{name:'a',id:'socketId'},{name:'b',id:'socketId'},{name:'c',id:'socketId'},{name:'d',id:'socketId'}]
```

if you want to send message to user b only just loop through the array and match the name property and when you find the matching name just fetch the id of that user and send it away

```
for(let i=0 ; i<users.length ; i++){
     if(users[i].name == 'b'){
        io.to(users[i].id).emit('hey', 'How are you');
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is a good explanation, I will try to develop this in my app.

Comment: No problem just remember if you have a large number of users don't store data on server directly instead use mongo or redis.

Answer (score 0):

Every connection has a socket id but it will be different every time a user opens a new tab on the browser. So if a user opens two tabs, they will have two different socketIds.

So the better approach would be to use rooms. Every time a user connects you can add it to a room. The room name can be userId or email.

```
socket.join(userid)
```

Then whenever you want to send a message to a particular user just use

```
io.sockets.in(userid).emit('message',"hello");
```

This will work even if the user has multiple tabs open on their device.